# jQuery append() function not appending for each <p> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to JavaScript. Full code is [here](http://ideone.com/jiEaK8) (couldn't type jQuery in the question's body).

Following is the JS part of the code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        var newtext =  $("<b>It works!</b>");
        newtext.hide();
        $("p").append(newtext);
        newtext.fadeIn();
    });
});
```

What I intend to do is that when a user clicks on the button ("#btn1"), a new piece of text ("It works!"), should appear at the end of **each** `<p>` element of the HTML. But when I run the code, the text is appened to only the **last** `<p>` element. That is, if you open the source from the above link, you will see there are two `<p>` elements. But the "It works!" text is appended to only the second one.

How do I make this text append at the end of **each** `<p>` element?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is appending the text to each `<p>`. However, when you do the `.fadeIn()`, you're only affecting the last copy you appended.  Try changing that to

```
 $("p b").fadeIn();
```

Note that this solution is pretty simple, and it could cause weird effects if your HTML structure gets complicated. You could be a little more precise with something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var txtid = 1;
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        var newtext =  $("<b>It works!</b>").addClass("txt-" + txtid);
        newtext.hide();
        $("p").append(newtext);
        $("p .txt-" + id).fadeIn().removeClass("txt-" + txtid);
        txtid += 1;
    });
});
```

That adds a class to each block of text you insert. The class will be different for each button click, but shared by all the blocks of text inserted at the same time. That way, you ensure that your `.fadeIn()` call only affects the stuff you just inserted and not other stray `<b>` tags.

Comment: What does the 'b' do here?

Comment: it's selecting each `b` which is children of a `p`. @KevinRichards

Comment: @KevinRichards I'll extend the answer a little.

Comment: This one is so much better (and safer)! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try use .each(), like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#btn1").click(function(){
  $("p").each(function(index, elem){
    var newtext =  $("<b>It works!</b>");
        newtext.hide();
        $(elem).append(newtext);
        newtext.fadeIn();      
  });
 });
});
```

Sample : http://jsfiddle.net/wadehuang36/utzum522/

Answer (score 0):

The text is being appended to each `<p>`, but in last you are saying

```
 newtext.fadeIn();
```

So it's just fadding in last one. Instead of say like bellow.

```
 $("p").find('b').fadeIn();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/C7JJM/61/)

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn1").click(function(){
    var newtext =  $("<b>It works!</b>");
    $(newtext).hide("fast", function() {
        $("p").append(newtext).fadeIn();
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the text append to each `p` tag just remove this line `newtext.hide();`

so that your script would look like

```
 $("#btn1").click(function(){
    var newtext =  $("<b>It works!</b>");
    //newtext.hide();
    $("p").append(newtext);
    newtext.fadeIn();
  });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sunil_hari/Lu8j2s8p/)